# What is the fastest way of getting a file length in .net?

Tags: .net, file, file-io, fileinfo

What is the fastest way of getting a file length in .net?

Note: I am accessing files via a network share.

So far I have

- 1.5ms FileInfo.Length
- .5ms FileStream().Length

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's wrong with FileInfo?

Comment: Yes, if you explain why you can not use FileInfo, people are more likely to give the answer you are looking for

Comment: @Scott @Luxspes  I have re-worded the question to represent my true intent.

Comment: Their questions still apply. Is FileInfo.Length really not fast enough for you?

Comment: @notjim in my testing. access a file on a network. 1.5ms for FileInfo.Length. .5ms for new FileStream().Length. so when access large amount of files that makes for a fairly significant difference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Derived from Adi_aks answer

```
public static long GetFileLength(string path)
{
    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
    {
        return fileStream.Length;
    }
}
```

Comment: I added a `Catch ex As Exception Return -1 End Try End Function` (oops... my VB is showing..) to some code I'm using to do a tail with. Works like a charm, and seems leaner than using a FileInfo object.

Answer (score 2):

```
long size = File.OpenRead(path).Length;
```

Comment: Server.MapPath() would only apply in ASP.NET, and I'm not sure the fastest way to find a file size would involve unnecessarily opening a stream on it (that, incidentally, is not being closed by this code, too)

Comment: better yet to do 
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
{
 var length = fileStream.Length;
}

Answer (score 1):

You could PInvoke the FindFirstFile or [GetFileAttributesEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364946%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) API calls, but that seems like a lot of extra work that the FileInfo class is already doing for you.  Otherwise I'm wondering the same thing Scott is: why would you not want to use FileInfo?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use `FileInfo.Length`?

You could p/invoke the Win32 APIs: CreateFile, GetFileSizeEx, and CloseHandle if you really wanted to.

Comment: I have re-worded the question to represent my true intent.